# Does smoothed data work better for time series forecasting with LSTMs?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, lstm, exponential-smoothing

I am training a 3-layer LSTM on time series data ($10^6$ training samples) to predict the next point in the time series, where there is no seasonality and

- the time series has been made stationary (using the backshift operator as outlined by Lopez in *Advances in Financial Machine Learning* - Chapter 5, Fractionally Differentiated Features). Explicitly, if we have a time series $X_t$, then

$$\tilde{X}_t = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \omega_kX_{t-k}$$
where
$$\omega = \{ 1, -d, \frac{d(d-1)}{2!}, -\frac{d(d-1)(d-2)}{3!}, ..., (-1)^k\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{d-i}{k!},...
\}$$

where $d$ is the degree of fractional differentiation (I chose $d=0.45$) and I have truncated $\omega$ up to $10^{-5}$. $\tilde{X}_t$ is now the stationary time series. I measure stationarity by the [Augmented Dickey Fuller Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test); if the ADF statistic is below -2.86, then I categorize the time series as stationary.

- exponential smoothing has been applied (halflife of 10 periods)
- the data has been scaled to $[0,1]$

in that order.

All else being left the same, I find that the RMSE on test data is much lower (about 5 times lower) if I **do not** smooth the data. I can't understand why this would be so.

Intuitively, I would have thought that less noisy data would yield higher accuracy (lower error). In researching resources online, I found [this paper](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0925231218311639?token=12A4BF578A58898D13EDD2BD371130CBCD6BB5C733E774074183B3E3734D3D46D5F9BB6F0FA1DF4361E86B7A6102F38B) where the authors also use an LSTM for time series forecasting and pre-process their data in a similar way (although the order of their pre-processing is different and they apply a simple moving average rather than exponential moving average).

I have two questions:

**1. Is there some reason why an LSTM would perform better on noisy data than on smooth data?** Is there any literature on this?

**2. Does the ordering of preprocessing matter?** In other words, should scaling come before smoothing or vice versa? If so, why / why not?

Comment: "The time series has been made stationary" - a lot of sins can be hidden in those seven words!   Could you expand on what you did?

Comment: @jbowman sure, I edited the question to explain how and gave a link to the relevant material

Comment: @PyRsquared You just referenced ~400 page document as an explanation of how you made your series stationary.  Care to be more specific?

Comment: @Barker that's strange; the link was working for me last night but this morning I get the same error as you. Anyway, I've edited the question to include the explicit formula I am using :)